# Using request validation for ajax queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss

Users on my site have a page they can write their own html to. I want this to be used for things like ordered lists, styling, and so on, but some people will try to insert script, which I can't allow.

The mechanism for updating a user's description is through ajax. From javascript, I send a request to a file `ajax.ashx`, which calls a function in `ajaxMethods.cs`. In the function I update the sql server with the user's new description.

How can I validate the input in the function, before the description is submited to the server? I want to take out anything to do with scripting, but leave the normal html tags like `<p>`. Are there any tools that will handle all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not allow users to use a custom format / language instead (for example [Markdown](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)) and then parse this server side to HTML? This way you know that any script / html code you find within the actual request is invalid and can be stripped (or encoded). This also gives you the advantage of only allow a predetermined list of tags. It would basically give you the same functionality as StackOverflow has.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) your output. Trying to parse out the script tags and not the HTML is not a good approach.  See reference below:

[XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use HtmlEncode because that encodes all the tags, while I need some tags to remain, but script tags to be removed.

Comment: I am just telling you if you try to parse HTML to only remove script tags you will run into problems and your solution won't stop common XSS attacks.  There is a reason ASP.NET MVC encodes all output by default. :)